# ¿De qué forma puedo usar List<T> con File.ReadAllText en C#?

Tags: c#

Mi objetivo es comprobar la existencia de nombres en un `List<T>` dentro de un archivo *.txt*.

Esto es algo que he estado viendo; necesito a todos en un `List<T>`.

```
List<string> listnames = new List<string>
{
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3",
    "name4"
};

string fileExists = @".\Names\Names.txt";

if (File.ReadAllText(fileExists).Contains("name1")) //implementar List aqui
{
    WpfMessageBox.Show("Aviso", "¡¡ listnames estan !!", MessageBoxButton.OK, 3);
}
else
{
    WpfMessageBox.Show("Error", "¡¡ listnames no estan !!", MessageBoxButton.OK, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que recorrer la lista e ir preguntando si el valor existe

```
public void NombreFuncion()
{
    List<string> listnames = new List<string>
    {
        "name1",
        "name2",
        "name3",
        "name4"
    };

    string fileExists = @".\Names\Names.txt";
    string texto = File.ReadAllText(fileExists);
    if (ExisteNombre(listnames,texto)) //implementar List aqui
    {
        WpfMessageBox.Show("Aviso", "¡¡ listnames estan !!", MessageBoxButton.OK, 3);
    }
    else
    {
        WpfMessageBox.Show("Error", "¡¡ listnames no estan !!", MessageBoxButton.OK, 4);
    }
}

public bool ExisteNombre(List<string> listnames, string texto) {
    foreach (string name in listnames)
    {
        if(!texto.Contains(name))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Esa es la lógica del asunto, pero en vez de crear una función puedes usar las que tiene C#

```
    string texto = File.ReadAllText(fileExists);
    
    //todas estas también funcionan
    //if (listnames.All(texto.Contains)
    //if (listnames.All(a=>texto.Contains(a))
    //if (listnames.TrueForAll(a=>texto.Contains(a)) 
    if (listnames.TrueForAll(texto.Contains)
    {
        WpfMessageBox.Show("Aviso", "¡¡ listnames estan !!", MessageBoxButton.OK, 3);
    }
    else
    {
        WpfMessageBox.Show("Error", "¡¡ listnames no estan !!", MessageBoxButton.OK, 4);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora entiendo un poco mejor iré estudiándolo :)

Comment: @RailinOrtiz  De nada, un gusto haber podido ayudarte

Comment: @Yussef en tu codigo, no es mejor hacerlo de esta manera? `return listnames.Any(name => texto.Contains(name));` si contiene el texto retornara true en caso contrario un false

Comment: @Daniel `Any` retornará `true` si existe una o más palabras de la lista en el texto. En cambio `All` retorna `true` si TODAS las palabras de la lista están en el texto.

Comment: @Yussef me refería en tu método `ExisteNombre`, porque ahí recorres todo con `foreach`

Comment: @Daniel Quise poner una función que no ocupara funciones de `linq`, creo que así se puede entender la lógica del asunto. En ese método se recorre todo el array solo si encuentra todas las palabras, el `for` de detiene (por el return) si una palabra de la lista no se encuentra

Answer (score 4):

Para que verifique todas es tan simple como hacer la verificación para cada elemento de la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```
static bool ContieneTodos(string cadena, List<string> subcadenas){
    foreach (string subcadena un subcadenas)
        if (!cadena.Contains(subcadena))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Para que quede más claro por qué lo hice así: es más fácil verificar que no todos los elementos se encuentran en la lista. Con un solo elemento que no esté es suficiente para decir que no están todos.

---

También puedes hacerlo con [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all):

```
lista.All(subcadena => cadena.Contains(subcadena));
```